# Rspec + phantomjs/poltergeist GITLAB CI fails to run integration/feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, gitlab-ci

Hi I am struggling to run my integration/feature tests via the Ci, please do let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Running specs locally works without any issues

The strangeness of this is that it dose not want to run because it seems to have problems finding application .css or .js

the gitlab CI setup :

```
image: ruby:2.3.0

cache:
paths:
- .bundle
- vendor/

stages:
 - test
 - integration
 - codecov

before_script:
 - export COMPILE=0
 - export PHANTOM_JS=phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
 - export RAILS_ENV=test
 - gem install bundler
 - bundle install --path vendor/
 - mkdir ~/tmp
 - pushd ~/tmp
 - wget --max-redirect=40 
   http://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
 - tar xf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
 - mv $PHANTOM_JS phantomjs
 - ln -s ~/tmp/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
 - phantomjs --version
 - popd
rspec:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:latest
    - redis:latest
variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: package_analysis_test
    POSTGRES_USER: runner
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner

  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq nodejs postgresql-
      client libpq-dev
    - gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
    - cp config/_database.yml config/database.yml
    - cp config/_redis.yml config/redis.yml
    - cp config/_sidekiq.yml config/sidekiq.yml
    - cp config/_settings.yml config/settings.yml
    - bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:structure:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec --exclude-pattern spec/features/*_spec.rb
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/

rspec-integration:
  stage: integration
  services:
    - postgres:latest
    - redis:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: package_analysis_test
    POSTGRES_USER: runner
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner

  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq nodejs postgresql-
      client libpq-dev
    - gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
    - cp config/_database.yml config/database.yml
    - cp config/_redis.yml config/redis.yml
    - cp config/_sidekiq.yml config/sidekiq.yml
    - cp config/_settings.yml config/settings.yml
    - bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:structure:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec spec/features
pages:
  stage: codecov
  dependencies:
    - rspec
  script:
    - mv coverage/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
  only:
    - staging
```

this is how the 'head' of the error looks like:

```
1) User processes late orders entering late orders #index
   Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #
  {env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

    ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css"
     # /builds/justcode/packageanalysis/vendor/ruby/2.3.0/gems/web-console-
   2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
    # /builds/justcode/packageanalysis/vendor/ruby/2.3.0/gems/web-console-
  2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
   # /builds/justcode/packageanalysis/vendor/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-
   4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    # /builds/justcode/packageanalysis/vendor/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in 
   `call_app'
```

Once its the application js the other tie its the css file. I am confused on what to do with this

this is also my capybara setup from the test helpers :

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/rails'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    js_errors: true,
    cookies: true,
    inspector: true,
    window_size: [2_500, 2_500]
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_selector = :css
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the `web_console` gem in your test group.  Beyond that, what settings to you have for `config.public_file_server.*` and `config.assets.*` in your `config/environments/test.rb` ?

Comment: Hi big thanks for Your answer. The only setting I currently have from the listed above is `config.assets.compile = ENV['COMPILE'].blank? ? true : false`
 
When run with Gitlab CI it is set for true / locally its false.

I have read in a few articles that this would fix the problem but obviously it did not.

Also `config.public_file_server.*` with no setting defaults to true

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to move to headless chrome and use my own image.

https://hub.docker.com/r/grfx/ruby-chromedriver/ 
(ruby 2.3, chromedriver 2.33, node, postgresql-client)

ALSO do **turn off caching** for the time between now and merge to master(main) branch if You used a different image setting.

The gitlab-ci setup was reduced to essential settings :

```
image: 'grfx/ruby-chromedriver:latest'

cache:
  paths:
    #- .bundle
    #- vendor/
    #- public/

stages:
  - test
  - codecov

before_script:
  - export RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle install --path vendor/
rspec:
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:latest
    - redis:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: package_analysis_test
    POSTGRES_USER: runner
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner

  script:
    - cp config/_database.yml config/database.yml
    - cp config/_redis.yml config/redis.yml
    - cp config/_sidekiq.yml config/sidekiq.yml
    - cp config/_settings.yml config/settings.yml
    - bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:structure:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
      - public/

pages:
  stage: codecov
  dependencies:
    - rspec
  script:
    - mv coverage/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
  only:
    - staging
```

gems used :

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.9'
gem 'webdrivers'
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.16.1'
```

rspec setup (rails_helper)

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara/rails'


Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w(headless disable-gpu no-sandbox)
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Capybara.default_selector = :css
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using single quotes instead of double quotes when defining the route:

`"No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] # {env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"`

Comment: Hi thank You for the comment. I do believe this is more the GitlabCi way of handling the reading of variables. I do not believe I have control over that